# JMeter load test time frame

Tags: testing, jmeter

I'm doing load test using JMeter, I have 1 thread group which simulate user browsing pages, the load I want to test is 600 users in 1 hour time frame, so I configured my thread group as `Number of Threads: 600` and `Ramp-Up Period: 3600`. However the test run 5 hours to finish, so I'm not sure the time frame of the test, is it 1 hour or 5 hours?

Comment: Please share the snapshot of your thread group. 3600 seconds will take to inject 600 users. May I know the duration of your test? Also, have you enabled the `Loop count` to `forever`.

Comment: Loop count 1, Forever unchecked. I do have a couple of Uniform Random Timers in between HTTP Requests.

Comment: I guess your test would have completed 1 hour or more. You can validate this by checking the jmeter.log file or in the View Results Tree listener. But you are not simulating real world scenario. 3600 seconds ramp up time is too much.

Answer (score 1):

"Ramp up" means "the time something needed to get to full extent/power".

So your test would be slowly increasing the load it puts onto system under test from 0 to 600 threads during 1 hour.

If you need to test your stuff for exactly one hour - use Scheduler & Duration options to configure that.

As for ramp up - it depends on the system you're testing: if it is kind of scalable, starts from few and needs time to spin up additional resources - give it that time to warm up.

And last but not least: 600 threads is quite a lot, you may need to do some extra steps to make it going - like, distributed testing, or, if machine is powerful enough and well-equipped with a thick networking, revise the JMeter start script default settings and give it more memory.